What does SEGGER Embedded Studio's Use Compiler Driver option do
I found that when using SEGGER Embedded Studio with the Use Compiler Driver option configured to Yes, my print function was not affected by Libary I/O configuration changes.
What does the Use Compiler Driver option do? I didn't find a detailed description in the official help documentation
I searched the official help documentation and couldn't find a detailed description

A "compiler driver" is a language independent entry point to build tools.  Segger's compiler driver is cc.  It invokes the appropriate compiler (or the assembler) depending on the filename extension of the translation unit it is presented with, and can also invoke the linker. It simplifies mixed language builds.
It is documented by Segger here: https://studio.segger.com/cc.htm
It is not clear from the documentation, but for C++ there is a specific driver cc++.  C++ requires additional libraries and runtime start-up code to be linked and using cc++ presumably enables that.  If it is like the GNU gcc and gcc++ drivers, that will be the case.  You can in that case compile C++ with cc, but will need to explicitly link the appropriate start-up code and libraries. Note cc++ will also compile C or assemble.  In your case no doubt the IDE will use the appropriate driver when you specify a C or C++ project.
